# FMI function for MI datasets is acting up?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I used the fmi function from SemTools package just a few weeks ago, and it worked great! Here is the code that I saved and that worked fine:

```
dat.imp2 <- mice(data = dat1, m = 37, method = "pmm", seed = 444)
out <- fmi(dat.imp2$imputations)
out
```

I have used it to compare the loss of efficiency in using 4 source variables vs 1 composite, so I re-ran it twice - first with the 4 source variables and then with 1 composite, and it was much better for composite. Also, the output showed fmi for means and variances separately.

Come back to this code a few weeks later, and it doens't work! The error message reads:

```
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 0] do not match the length of object [1]
```

So, I modified the code as follows:

```
imp2 <- mice(dat1, m = 37, method = "pmm", seed = 444)
out <- fmi(imp2$data)
out
```

This works but only with the composite variable in the dataset, and only gives me fmi for means but not variances. If I substitute this composite variable with the four source variables it gives me the following error:
Warning message:

```
In lavaan(slotOptions = object@Options, slotParTable = object@ParTable,  :
  lavaan WARNING: model has NOT converged!
```

I don't understand how the code that worked a couple weeks ago does not work now? Did anyone come across this problem? I wasn't able to find much online.
Thank you!

---

Here is the dataset with one composite variable instead (mommh)

```
> dput(dat2)
structure(list(mompa = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), momabhx = structure(c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), 
    mommh = c(63, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35.75, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.25, NA, NA, 63, 41.5, 
    34.25, 38.5, 39, 38.5, NA, 49.75, 57.5, 59.25, 50, 42.75, 
    45, 49, 32.75, NA, 35.75, 64.75, 50.5, 46.5, 39.75, 51.75, 
    34.75, 61.25, 46, 43, 56.25, 47, 42.25, 36.5, 34.5, 47, 50, 
    35, 48.25, 46.5, 58.5, 35.5, 55.25, 43.5, 42.75, 35.75, 38, 
    35.5, 50, 38.25, 57, 45.75, 38.5, 44.25, 51.75, NA, 38.25, 
    39.75, 34, 57.25, 39.25, 42.25, 37.25, NA, 32.75, 52.75, 
    NA, NA, 55.75, 62.25, 59.75, 43.75, 59.75, 35.75, NA, 34.25, 
    59.25, 39, 34.75, 32.75, NA, 53.5, NA, 40.5, 50, 33.5, 45.25, 
    41, 50, NA, 38.5, 61.5, 36.25, 46.25, 46, 44.75, 44.75, 62.5, 
    38.25, 49.5, 33.75, NA, 50.25, 43, 43.75, 42.25, 60.5, NA, 
    50.25, 54.75, 42.75, 45.75, 61, 58.25, 44.5, 46.5, 34.25, 
    56.75, 40.5, 47, 42.25, 48, 44, 36.75, 39.75, 48.75, 38.25, 
    49.25, 49.25, NA, NA, 34.25, 44.5, NA, 51, 44, 50.75, 56.25, 
    35, 55, 58.75, 56.5, 68.75, 54, 53, 41.5, 50.75, NA, 32.75, 
    46.75, 32.75, 43, 57, 55.25, NA, NA, 43.75, 55.5, NA, NA, 
    32.75, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60.5, 32.75, NA, 68.25, 50.5, 32.75, 
    66.5, 33, 38.5, 43, 43.75, 62.75, 47, 36.5, 39.5, 39.5), 
    risk6 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, NA, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
    3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
    2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
    3, 2, 2), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), eadiff = structure(c(-1.26734803867686, 
    -0.355541076313792, 0.518653050779668, 1.50568568368194, 
    0.0940935989894723, 2.07356799670629, 1.01843817310907, -1.26734803867686, 
    -0.317928241044189, 0.531190662536203, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -1.47335895869369, -0.586627219843691, -1.26734803867686, 
    0.325179742519372, 0.556265886049271, 1.4179224013862, 1.2244490931259, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.081555987232938, -0.149530156296961, 
    -0.380616299826861, -0.805175751617057, -0.368078688070326, 
    0.0940935989894723, -0.124454932783893, 0.955750114326398, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.531190662536203, -0.830250975130125, 
    0.968287726082933, 0.749739194309568, -0.368078688070326, 
    -1.03626189514696, 3.19138587908619, -0.574089608087157, 
    1.67408376842917, -0.586627219843691, -0.343003464557258, 
    -0.162067768053496, 0.325179742519372, -1.24227281516379, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.749739194309568, 0.325179742519372, 
    0.556265886049271, 0.762276806066102, -0.817713363373591, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.119168822502541, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.149530156296961, 0.0940935989894723, -1.48589657045022, 
    1.01843817310907, 0.312642130762837, 1.21191148136937, -0.355541076313792, 
    -1.04879950690349, -0.368078688070326, -0.124454932783893, 
    0.312642130762837, -1.25481042692032, -0.136992544540427, 
    1.01843817310907, -0.124454932783893, -0.368078688070326, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.081555987232938, -0.805175751617057, 
    0.325179742519372, 2.97283734731282, 0.337717354275906, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.136992544540427, -0.830250975130125, 3.03552540609549, 
    0.0940935989894723, 0.0690183754764037, -0.124454932783893, 
    -0.817713363373591, -0.355541076313792, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.980825337839467, -0.343003464557258, 0.993362949596001, 
    -0.586627219843691, -0.574089608087157, -1.02372428339042, 
    -0.561551996330623, -0.111917321027358, -0.136992544540427, 
    -0.149530156296961, -0.830250975130125, 0.568803497805805, 
    0.0690183754764037, -0.805175751617057, -0.830250975130125, 
    0.556265886049271, 0.968287726082933, 0.531190662536203, 
    0.312642130762837, 0.337717354275906, 0.774814417822636, 
    0.337717354275906, 0.337717354275906, -0.586627219843691, 
    0.106631210746007, -1.02372428339042, -0.574089608087157, 
    -0.355541076313792, 0.737201582553033, 0.325179742519372, 
    0.312642130762837, 0.556265886049271, 0.0940935989894723, 
    0.300104519006303, -0.330465852800723, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.355541076313792, -0.599164831600226, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.531190662536203, -1.25481042692032, 0.531190662536203, 
    1.89263230020253, -0.817713363373591, -1.02372428339042, 
    0.980825337839467, -0.149530156296961, -0.586627219843691, 
    1.23698670488244, 0.556265886049271, 0.325179742519372, -0.817713363373591, 
    1.01843817310907, -1.02372428339042, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.355541076313792, 1.67408376842917, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.368078688070326, -0.124454932783893, 0.980825337839467, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.119168822502541, -1.03626189514696, 
    -1.03626189514696, 1.4555352366558, -0.136992544540427, -1.04879950690349, 
    0.749739194309568, -0.792638139860522, 0.312642130762837, 
    -0.0993797092708241, -0.17460537981003, -0.343003464557258, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.300104519006303, -0.355541076313792, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.518653050779668, -1.26734803867686, 
    -1.25481042692032, -0.368078688070326, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.343003464557258, -0.343003464557258, -0.599164831600226, 
    -0.124454932783893, 1.66154615667263, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.586627219843691, -0.124454932783893, 0.955750114326398, 
    -0.355541076313792, -0.343003464557258, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.792638139860522, -0.599164831600226, NA, -0.586627219843691, 
    -1.26734803867686, 0.762276806066102, 1.2244490931259, 0.081555987232938, 
    -0.574089608087157, -1.01118667163389, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.081555987232938, -0.368078688070326, -1.26734803867686, 
    1.63647093315956, -0.368078688070326, 0.531190662536203, 
    0.081555987232938, 0.543728274292737, 0.0564807637198694, 
    0.955750114326398, -1.25481042692032, 1.44299762489927, -1.04879950690349, 
    0.106631210746007, -0.586627219843691, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.162067768053496, 0.0940935989894723, -0.111917321027358, 
    0.968287726082933, 0.0940935989894723, 0.312642130762837, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.543728274292737, -0.124454932783893, 
    0.543728274292737, -0.817713363373591, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.368078688070326, 0.0940935989894723, -0.599164831600226, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.774814417822636, 0.106631210746007, 
    -0.111917321027358, -0.817713363373591, -0.330465852800723, 
    0.993362949596001, -0.368078688070326, 1.19937386961283, 
    0.531190662536203, 0.749739194309568, 1.6490085449161, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.574089608087157, -0.368078688070326, 1.00590056135254, 
    1.4555352366558, -0.574089608087157, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.817713363373591, -0.817713363373591, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.792638139860522, 0.0690183754764037), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L)), .Names = c("mompa", 
"momabhx", "mommh", "risk6", "eadiff"), row.names = c(NA, -244L
), class = "data.frame")
```

---

And here is the same dataset with 4 source variables (depr, anxt, host, bpsipdr1)

```
> dput(dat3)
structure(list(mompa = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), momabhx = structure(c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), 
    risk6 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, NA, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
    3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
    2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
    3, 2, 2), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), eadiff = structure(c(-1.26734803867686, 
    -0.355541076313792, 0.518653050779668, 1.50568568368194, 
    0.0940935989894723, 2.07356799670629, 1.01843817310907, -1.26734803867686, 
    -0.317928241044189, 0.531190662536203, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -1.47335895869369, -0.586627219843691, -1.26734803867686, 
    0.325179742519372, 0.556265886049271, 1.4179224013862, 1.2244490931259, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.081555987232938, -0.149530156296961, 
    -0.380616299826861, -0.805175751617057, -0.368078688070326, 
    0.0940935989894723, -0.124454932783893, 0.955750114326398, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.531190662536203, -0.830250975130125, 
    0.968287726082933, 0.749739194309568, -0.368078688070326, 
    -1.03626189514696, 3.19138587908619, -0.574089608087157, 
    1.67408376842917, -0.586627219843691, -0.343003464557258, 
    -0.162067768053496, 0.325179742519372, -1.24227281516379, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.749739194309568, 0.325179742519372, 
    0.556265886049271, 0.762276806066102, -0.817713363373591, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.119168822502541, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.149530156296961, 0.0940935989894723, -1.48589657045022, 
    1.01843817310907, 0.312642130762837, 1.21191148136937, -0.355541076313792, 
    -1.04879950690349, -0.368078688070326, -0.124454932783893, 
    0.312642130762837, -1.25481042692032, -0.136992544540427, 
    1.01843817310907, -0.124454932783893, -0.368078688070326, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.081555987232938, -0.805175751617057, 
    0.325179742519372, 2.97283734731282, 0.337717354275906, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.136992544540427, -0.830250975130125, 3.03552540609549, 
    0.0940935989894723, 0.0690183754764037, -0.124454932783893, 
    -0.817713363373591, -0.355541076313792, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.980825337839467, -0.343003464557258, 0.993362949596001, 
    -0.586627219843691, -0.574089608087157, -1.02372428339042, 
    -0.561551996330623, -0.111917321027358, -0.136992544540427, 
    -0.149530156296961, -0.830250975130125, 0.568803497805805, 
    0.0690183754764037, -0.805175751617057, -0.830250975130125, 
    0.556265886049271, 0.968287726082933, 0.531190662536203, 
    0.312642130762837, 0.337717354275906, 0.774814417822636, 
    0.337717354275906, 0.337717354275906, -0.586627219843691, 
    0.106631210746007, -1.02372428339042, -0.574089608087157, 
    -0.355541076313792, 0.737201582553033, 0.325179742519372, 
    0.312642130762837, 0.556265886049271, 0.0940935989894723, 
    0.300104519006303, -0.330465852800723, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.355541076313792, -0.599164831600226, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.531190662536203, -1.25481042692032, 0.531190662536203, 
    1.89263230020253, -0.817713363373591, -1.02372428339042, 
    0.980825337839467, -0.149530156296961, -0.586627219843691, 
    1.23698670488244, 0.556265886049271, 0.325179742519372, -0.817713363373591, 
    1.01843817310907, -1.02372428339042, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.355541076313792, 1.67408376842917, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.368078688070326, -0.124454932783893, 0.980825337839467, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.119168822502541, -1.03626189514696, 
    -1.03626189514696, 1.4555352366558, -0.136992544540427, -1.04879950690349, 
    0.749739194309568, -0.792638139860522, 0.312642130762837, 
    -0.0993797092708241, -0.17460537981003, -0.343003464557258, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.300104519006303, -0.355541076313792, 
    -0.805175751617057, 0.518653050779668, -1.26734803867686, 
    -1.25481042692032, -0.368078688070326, -0.805175751617057, 
    -0.343003464557258, -0.343003464557258, -0.599164831600226, 
    -0.124454932783893, 1.66154615667263, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.586627219843691, -0.124454932783893, 0.955750114326398, 
    -0.355541076313792, -0.343003464557258, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.792638139860522, -0.599164831600226, NA, -0.586627219843691, 
    -1.26734803867686, 0.762276806066102, 1.2244490931259, 0.081555987232938, 
    -0.574089608087157, -1.01118667163389, 0.312642130762837, 
    0.081555987232938, -0.368078688070326, -1.26734803867686, 
    1.63647093315956, -0.368078688070326, 0.531190662536203, 
    0.081555987232938, 0.543728274292737, 0.0564807637198694, 
    0.955750114326398, -1.25481042692032, 1.44299762489927, -1.04879950690349, 
    0.106631210746007, -0.586627219843691, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.162067768053496, 0.0940935989894723, -0.111917321027358, 
    0.968287726082933, 0.0940935989894723, 0.312642130762837, 
    -0.586627219843691, 0.543728274292737, -0.124454932783893, 
    0.543728274292737, -0.817713363373591, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.368078688070326, 0.0940935989894723, -0.599164831600226, 
    -1.03626189514696, 0.774814417822636, 0.106631210746007, 
    -0.111917321027358, -0.817713363373591, -0.330465852800723, 
    0.993362949596001, -0.368078688070326, 1.19937386961283, 
    0.531190662536203, 0.749739194309568, 1.6490085449161, 0.0690183754764037, 
    -0.574089608087157, -0.368078688070326, 1.00590056135254, 
    1.4555352366558, -0.574089608087157, -0.586627219843691, 
    -0.817713363373591, -0.817713363373591, 0.0940935989894723, 
    -0.792638139860522, 0.0690183754764037), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), 
    host = structure(c(68, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41, 49, 41, 78, 41, 41, 
    49, 41, 45, 45, 51, 71, 73, 62, 51, 51, 65, 38, NA, 38, 70, 
    58, 45, 38, 64, 38, 72, 55, 45, 60, 58, 38, 38, 38, 38, 45, 
    38, 38, 51, 60, 38, 68, 51, 60, 38, 45, 38, 38, 38, 68, 45, 
    38, 51, 51, NA, 45, 38, 38, 66, 38, 45, 38, 65, 38, 51, NA, 
    NA, 60, 71, 70, 45, 71, 38, NA, 38, 55, 38, 38, 38, NA, 62, 
    58, 38, 58, 38, 51, 38, 72, 64, 45, 71, 45, 45, 51, 45, 45, 
    75, 38, 51, 38, 58, 55, 55, 38, 38, 70, 55, 65, 64, 55, 55, 
    69, 68, 55, 38, 38, 55, 45, 58, 38, 64, 38, 51, 45, 45, 38, 
    45, 62, 66, NA, 38, 45, 58, 58, 51, 65, 64, 38, 60, 60, 70, 
    75, 65, 62, 51, 62, NA, 38, 58, 38, 45, 38, 65, NA, 64, 38, 
    51, NA, NA, 38, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70, 38, NA, 75, 55, 38, 71, 
    38, 38, 55, 55, 58, 58, 45, 45, 45), format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 11L), 
    anxt = structure(c(73, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51, 51, 51, 66, 51, 40, 
    40, 51, 55, 62, 55, 55, 67, 51, 55, 55, 65, 39, NA, 39, 62, 
    59, 59, 39, 67, 39, 62, 51, 51, 65, 51, 51, 51, 39, 51, 59, 
    39, 59, 55, 71, 39, 53, 51, 51, 51, 51, 39, 55, 39, 65, 59, 
    51, 39, 65, NA, 39, 51, 39, 65, 51, 51, 39, 59, 39, 67, NA, 
    NA, 59, 70, 67, 39, 65, 39, NA, 39, 65, 51, 39, 39, NA, 62, 
    65, 55, 39, 39, 59, 39, 70, NA, 55, 67, 39, 51, 55, 51, 55, 
    70, 55, 56, 39, 70, 55, 51, 51, 51, 62, NA, 59, 62, 55, 59, 
    62, 59, 51, 51, 39, 65, 39, 55, 62, 51, 55, 39, 39, 62, 51, 
    55, 62, NA, NA, 39, 51, NA, 62, 39, 62, 59, 39, 59, 71, 51, 
    74, 59, 51, 51, 62, NA, 39, 51, 39, 51, 72, 62, NA, 62, 55, 
    62, NA, NA, 39, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70, 39, NA, 70, 65, 39, 73, 
    39, 51, 51, 55, 74, 62, 39, 51, 51), format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 11L), 
    depr = structure(c(71, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53, 68, NA, 71, 44, 44, 
    44, 44, 42, 42, 61, 64, 57, 70, 42, 50, 54, 42, NA, 50, 78, 
    57, 50, 42, 54, 42, 68, 42, 54, 64, 54, 54, 42, 42, 68, 64, 
    42, 65, 50, 68, 42, 70, 50, 42, 42, 42, 42, 50, 42, 60, 54, 
    42, 56, 64, NA, 42, 42, 42, 61, 42, 42, 42, 57, 42, 64, 57, 
    NA, 68, 73, 72, 57, 68, 42, 57, 42, 65, 50, 42, 42, NA, 62, 
    62, 42, 61, 42, 54, 54, 42, 71, 42, 64, 42, 54, 54, 57, 42, 
    70, 42, 54, 42, 57, 57, 54, 60, 54, 71, 60, 54, 60, 42, 42, 
    68, 70, 50, 60, 42, 69, 54, 42, 42, 57, 50, 42, 42, 54, 42, 
    65, 57, 68, NA, 42, 60, 64, 50, 60, 50, 70, 42, 65, 64, 65, 
    71, 64, 62, 42, 62, NA, 42, 42, 42, 57, 70, 61, NA, 57, 42, 
    68, NA, NA, 42, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 42, NA, 75, 61, 42, 75, 
    42, 42, 54, 50, 72, 42, 50, 42, 42), format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 11L), 
    bpsipdr1 = structure(c(40, 26, 34, 29, 23, 41, 37, 21, 38, 
    NA, 33, 28, 25, NA, NA, 15, 18, 30, NA, NA, 28, 34, NA, 51, 
    24, 28, 23, 12, 39, 55, 28, NA, 26, 18, 33, NA, 27, 32, 27, 
    23, 28, 41, NA, 22, 21, 26, 26, 36, 16, 24, 24, 25, 23, 24, 
    26, 35, 32, 27, 38, 25, 26, 32, 27, 41, 28, NA, 27, 37, 30, 
    12, 21, 20, 12, NA, 32, 40, 40, 17, 23, 24, 12, 12, NA, 16, 
    49, 28, 32, 40, 22, 20, 43, 36, 22, 36, 25, 26, 15, 19, 31, 
    32, 21, 31, 30, 35, 23, 30, 22, 18, 12, 14, 23, 57, 34, 35, 
    25, 23, 31, 27, 33, 27, 28, 17, 37, 26, 31, 30, NA, 12, 29, 
    NA, 19, 36, 35, 30, 34, 35, 24, 34, 18, 52, 17, 20, 12, 25, 
    28, NA, 27, 42, 15, 17, 33, 16, 30, 12, 44, 19, 35, 24, 26, 
    37, 35, 18, 37, 16, NA, 34, 12, 26, 26, 39, 34, 23, 33, 19, 
    27, 45, 36, 22, 37, 18, 38, 24, 33, 27, 20, 33, 15, 33, 34, 
    22, 32, 16, 30, 24, 18, 22, 42, 34, 26, 26, 32, 21, 36, 40, 
    40, 55, 28, 37, 22, 17, 41, 12, 36, 12, 19, 48, 33, 26, NA, 
    40, 41, 24, 27, 12, 36, 24, 38, NA, 37, 12, 20, 53, 21, 12, 
    47, 13, 23, 12, 15, 47, 26, 12, 20, 20), format.spss = "F3.0", display_width = 11L)), .Names = c("mompa", 
"momabhx", "risk6", "eadiff", "host", "anxt", "depr", "bpsipdr1"
), row.names = c(NA, -244L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Well, something must have changed but there's not really enough information here to determine exactly what that might be. It's much easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data that we can use to run and test the code ourselves.

Comment: @MrFlick I uploaded both datasets: with 1 source variable (mommh) and with 4 source variables instead (depr, host, anxt, bpsipdr1). The "fmi(dat$imputations)" command doesn't work with either one (but worked before and gave out fmi mean and var.the "fmi(dat$data) works only with dat3 but not dat2 and only gives fmi foro means.Thank you for looking at it!!